# Can't replace objects with number in the dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to replace number with another number in the dictionary.

```
  [[[chatRoomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"notification_status"] replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

`@"notification_status"`  contain `NSNumber`.

But getting error :

```
[__NSCFNumber replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15637e80
```

How to do this?

Comment: yes and its NSNumber

Comment: what is `chatRoomList` ?

Comment: 'chatRoomList' is 'NSMutableDictionary'

Comment: Use objectForKey or [], not valueForKey. Read the documentation of valueForKey. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @DxAndroid: 'chatRoomList' is 'NSMutableDictionary': I bet it's not. Because your code wouldn't make any sense, and would crash with a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the dictionary, not try to treat the number in the dictionary as an array:

```
[[chatRoomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@0 forKey:@"notification_status"];
```

Note this also uses `objectForKey` instead of `valueForKey` which is the appropriate method for `NSDictionary` access (your original uses KVC).

Answer (score 1):

If [chatRoomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] returns a NSMutableDictionary:

```
 [[chatRoomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"notification_status"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try solution something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                                    tempDict=[[self.lifeLineAllPostArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag] mutableCopy];
                                    NSInteger likeCount=[[tempDict objectForKey:@"likes"] intValue];
                                    likeCount++;

                                    [tempDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:likeCount] forKey:@"likes"];

                                    //update my_like
                                  //  my_dislike

                                    [tempDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] forKey:@"my_like"];


                                    [self.lifeLineAllPostArray replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:tempDict];
```

make sure that value return by "notification_status" value is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

if chatRoomList is the mutable dictionary, then below code working fine:

[[chatRoomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0] forKey:@"notification_status"];

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code and what you are actually doing.

You have an array of dictionaries.

You pick the dictionary at index indexPath.row.

You extract the value for the key "notification_status" which is a number.

Then you try to change the object at index indexPath.row in that notification_status number. Hello? Does that make any sense? Not to me!

What you want to do (possibly, it's guessing because your code doesn't anything sensible) is change the notification_status in that dictionary.

So extract the dictionary at indexPath.row. If you store mutable dictionaries, you can just change a value in the dictionary. If you store immutable dictionaries, you make a mutable copy, change it, make an immutable copy, and replace the dictionary stored in your object.

It is actually helpful to write that kind of thing over multiple lines; had you done that then the compiler would have told you that what you are trying to do is nonsense, instead of waiting until runtime.

And I'd consider using a mutable dictionary for storing data instead of an object a very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
chatRoomList[indexPath.row][@"notification_status"] = @0;
```